An estimate for a given stochastic process.
A stochastic process $Y(t)\in\mathbb{R}^n,t\in[0,\infty),Y(0)=0$, satisfies $\frac{d\mathbb{E}(Y(t))}{dt}\leq a$ in the ball $B(0,c)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$,$\frac{d\mathbb{E}(Y(t))}{dt}\leq b$ in the whole space, a key condition is $a<<b$.
I hope to get some conclusions (such as distribution or how long the time is with a certain probability) about the time of the process exit of the ball with order about $\frac{c}{a},$ because the growth rate of the process is predominantly controlled by $a$ in the ball.
From expectation to control the value of r.a. only I know is Chebyshev inequality, but couldn't reach the result I wanted.
